# React Render UI Before Redirect

Tags: reactjs

I am having problem rendering ui before redirect in react. I has a variable is called from api, i want to check if it is 'x' then will redirect. But ui will render before redirect.

Bellow is my code:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    getProfile().then((res) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      if (res) {
        redirectByUserType(res.data.type); // redirect to /home
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

I tried using useLayoutEffect but not working.

Please help me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to render until getProfile() has finished, then have a state variable which tracks whether it is finished. If it hasn't finished, return null to render nothing. If it has, return whatever you want to render. I would normally call this state variable `loading`, but you seem to already have one with that name, who's purpose i don't know. Maybe you can piggy back on that, maybe you need a separate one:

```
const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  getProfile().then(res => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    if(res) {
      redirectByUserType(res.data.type);
    } else {
      setReady(true)
    }
  });
}, []);

if (!ready) {
  return null;
}

return (
  <div>Something</div>
);
```